# Conditional Probability coin tossing

Tags: probability

I was going through some exercises on probability and came across a question. Two people A and B are tossing a fair coin with A tossing first. The process is repeated till someone gets a heads. What is the probability of A winning.

I came across a solution where it says since A tosses first, probability of A winning in first outcome is 1. If B tosses and wins then it's probability is 1/2. Then it goes on to state that  P(B) = 1/2 P(A) 
P(B) + P(A) = 1
Therefore P(A) = 2/3 and P(B) = 1/3

I could not grasp how the probability of A tossing first and winning is 1 and not 1/2. Is this solution correct. If it is could anyone please clarify my doubt. Thanks

Comment: I believe it is correct. If you about it, when A tosses he can win with a 1/2 chance. If he fails that doesn't yet say anything about B winning for sure. B has a 1/2 chance to win as well. So maybe 1/2+1/2?

I believe it might be something along these lines but I'm not sure.

Comment: @DylanMeeus, that does not work.

Comment: Hashtag, can you try to clarify what you mean by "in first outcome"?

Comment: @ DylanMeeus By A winning in first outcome I meant, that A tosses the coin(since the process starts with A) and the outcome is a head. So A wins with the coin being tossed only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you came across some form of the following argument. Let $p$ be the probability that the first player wins. What is the probability that the second player wins? With probability $\frac12$ the first player tosses tails, and in effect the game starts over with $B$ now becoming the first player and having probability $p$ of winning. Thus, $B$ wins precisely when $A$ tosses tails **and** $B$ then goes on to win as if he were the first player, so $B$ wins with probability $\frac12p$. Clearly $p+\frac12p=1$, so $p=\frac23$.

Comment: @ Brian Thanks a ton, Brian.

Comment: @Hashtag: You’re welcome.

Comment: @ Brian Is it possible to extend it beyond two people using the same logic.

Comment: @Hashtag: Yes, it is. With three players the same logic gives you $p+\frac12p+\frac14p=1$, so $p=\frac47$. In this game the second player wins with probability $\frac27$ and the third with probability $\frac17$. The series calculation for $p$ is that $$p=\frac12\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac18\right)^n=\frac1{2\left(1-\frac18\right)}=\frac47\;.$$

Answer (score 2):

The other way to do it, if you're not comfortable with this logic, is a geometric series.  The probability of a tails being tossed after $n-1$ trials and then tossing a heads on the $n^{th}$ trial is $(1/2)^{n-1}\cdot (1/2)=2^{-n}$.  Therefore the probability of $A$ winning is $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2k+1}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty 4^{-k}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{4}{3}=\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: @ Tim Thanks Tim, since your solution is generic I can use it elsewhere also.